# Como fazer múltiplos execute com PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Possuo um formulário de atualização de usuários bem simples, porém não estou conseguindo realizar o update com sucesso utilizando PDO e o mysql.

**Segue o trecho do código no qual estou com problemas:**

```
if (isset($_POST['ID'])){//Se informar o ID do usuário que deseja modificar
    $senha = strip_tags(sha1(md5(trim($_POST['senha']))));//criptografa a senha
    $ID = $_POST ['ID'];//recebe o ID informado pelo usuario para modificar no sql
    if (!empty($_POST['NEWID'])){//modifica o ID
        $sqlid = "UPDATE usuarios SET ID = :ID WHERE ID = $ID";
        $stmtid = $pdo->prepare($sqlid);
        $stmtid->bindParam(':ID', $_POST['NEWID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtid->execute();
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['usuario'])){//modifica o usuario
        $sqlusr = "UPDATE usuarios SET usuario = :usuario WHERE ID = $ID";
        $stmtusr = $pdo->prepare($sqlusr);
        $stmtusr->bindParam(':usuario', $_POST['usuario'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtusr->execute();
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['senha'])){//modifica a senha
        $sqlpass = "UPDATE usuarios SET senha = :senha WHERE ID = $ID";
        $stmtpass = $pdo->prepare($sqlpass);
        $stmtpass->bindParam(':senha', $senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtpass->execute();
    }
}
```

O problema é que eu consigo modificar apenas 1 desses itens de cada vez, se eu quiser modificar o ID eu consigo, mas caso eu coloque para modificar o usuário também ele modificará apenas o 1 item que no caso é o ID, meu objetivo é fazer com que apenas seja modificado os itens que o usuário digitar... Já tentei fazer uma execução apenas porém o problema persistiu..

Comment: Mas se você modifica o ID e depois tenta modificar o USUARIO, o ID da tabela não será o ID que você está comparando, mas sim o ID que está vindo por POST['NEWID'].

Comment: realmente, mas no caso já havia tentado fazer isso de uma só vez com o execute e mesmo assim persistiu, caso eu realizasse tudo junto ele não deveria fazer todos? visto que o ID só modificaria após o execute, bom de qualquer forma era realmente isso! Se puder responder a pergunta para fechar o tópico ficaria grato! realmente o mais díficil é enxergar nossos erros..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não tem pra que fazer vários `UPDATE`, você pode fazer somente um. Economizará tempo de execução porque terá menos requisições ao servidor:

```
if (isset($_POST['ID'])){//Se informar o ID do usuário que deseja modificar
    $senha = strip_tags(sha1(md5(trim($_POST['senha']))));//criptografa a senha
    $ID = $_POST ['ID'];//recebe o ID informado pelo usuario para modificar no sql
    if ((!empty($_POST['NEWID'])) || (!empty($_POST['usuario'])) || (!empty($_POST['senha']))){//Verifica se um dos campos foi passado
        $sql = "UPDATE usuarios SET";
        if (!empty($_POST['NEWID'])){//modifica o ID
            $sql .= " ID = :ID,";
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['usuario'])){//modifica o usuario
            $sql .= " usuario = :usuario,";
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['senha'])){//modifica a senha
            $sql .= " senha = :senha,";
        }
        substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql) - 1);
        $sql .= " WHERE ID = $ID";
        $stmtpass = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        if (!empty($_POST['NEWID'])) {
            $stmtpass->bindParam(':ID', $_POST['NEWID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['usuario'])) {
            $stmtpass->bindParam(':usuario', $_POST['usuario'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['senha'])) {
            $stmtpass->bindParam(':senha', $_POST['senha'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        $stmtpass->execute();
    }
}
```

Além de diminuir as chamadas ao servidor `MySQL`, também irá corrigir seu problema de não alterar o `usuario` após alterar `ID`.

Comment: o que isso faz? substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql) - 1); Já havia tentado fazer de uma só vez, irei rever o que estava errado, vlw.

Comment: `substr` serve para pegar uma parte de uma `string`, já o `strlen` conta quantos caracteres tem uma `string`.

Comment: Nesse caso, estou chamando essa função para retirar a ultima virgula que vai sobrar na `QUERY` antes do `WHERE`.

Comment: eu vi esse problema da virgula mesmo, no caso não está funcionando, fiz de um modo mais bruto colocando operandores AND e 7 IF (sim não é uma boa prática).